Connections on Vector Bundles
I am reading the book on Geometric Analysis by Jost and I am stuck on the derivation of $F = dA + A\wedge A.$ In particular I am not sure if I understand why
$$A \circ d \mu + A \circ A \mu = A\wedge A \mu.$$
I would be grateful if someone could explain why the above two identities hold. Here $\pi:E\to M$ is a vector bundle, $D$ is a metric connection the reimannian manifold $M$. Locally we write $D=d+A$ where $A$ is Lie Algebra valued 1-form on $M$, $\mu \in \Gamma(E)$ is a section on $E$.


You are misreading this. The terms $-Ad\mu$ and $Ad\mu$ cancel. And there is no composition here. And the matrix $A$ of $1$-forms multiplies by $A\mu$ by wedging the $1$-forms and then acting on the vector-valued section.  Surely this is covered carefully in earlier parts of the text.

Thank you for pointing that out, I made a quick edit to my question!

First of all, $A\circ (-) =A\wedge(-)$ are definitionally the same, the left being the coordinate free "composition of $\Gamma(E)$-linear operators" and the right term being left multiplication by a matrix (of $1$-forms). Forms are multiplied using $\wedge$ notation, but it can be considered simply as matrix multiplication in the ring of coefficients $\Omega^*(E)$.
Secondly, the equation expands (with $d\circ d = 0$) like $$(d+A)\circ(d+A) = d\circ A + A\circ d + A\circ A$$
The first term is rewritten by Leibniz rule as $d\circ A = dA - A\wedge d$ which then cancels with the second term $A\circ d$ (which is the same as $A\wedge d$), leaving $dA + A\wedge A$. The term $A\circ d$ is not involved with $A\circ A$ in this calculation.
By the way, arguably $Ad\mu$ ought to be denoted $A\wedge d\mu$, or else $A\wedge A$ should be denoted $A^2$, as they both denote the same operation, which is multiplication of matrices of 1-forms.
